# Xcode 7.1 missing class template methods on El Capitan

Tags: xcode

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
- El Capitan 10.11.1
- Xcode 7.1 (7B91b)

When I do File > New > File, Subclass of: UICollectionViewController, I get an implementation file containing only:

> #import "CVCTest.h"
>
> @implementation CVCTest
>
> @end

So, there are none of the UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegate method stubs I expect. This is true for new UITableViewController and UIViewController subclass files as well.

This seems to be a suddenly new phenomenon; I created a UICollectionViewController subclass in a project last week which came with the stubbed methods. Xcode seems to have lost the class file templates.

After deleting the Xcode app and the ~/Library/Developer/Xcode directory, rebooting, and installing Xcode 7.1 from Mac AppStore, the behavior is the same.

I checked with on colleague whose Xcode behaves this way and then with another whose Xcode behaves as expected.

Anyone else experiencing this? Any clue what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. A critical piece of information I left out of my question is that I was subclassing a controller class for an iOS project. The "o.m.g" answer is that somehow

> OS X source

was selected at the bottom of the left pane of the source type selection view, instead of

> iOS source

With iOS source selected, I get the class template file with the expected stubbed methods.

wow.